# Selecting Data from JSON via PHP

Tags: json, json.net, jsonp

I have json data and i want to select some data plese read the json

```
 "response":{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"page":1,"current":0,"count":982,"pageCount":1,

"data":{"1131":{"OfferFile":
{"offer_id":"547"}},


"1525":{"OfferFile":{"offer_id":"717"}}

}
```

From above data i want to select 1131 and 1525 integers via php

Please give me a code snd thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the actual JSON that you have, when formatted properly, looks as follows:

```
{
    "status":1,
    "httpStatus":200,
    "page":1,
    "current":0,
    "count":982,
    "pageCount":1,
    "data":{
        "1131":{
            "OfferFile":{
                "offer_id":"547"
            }
        },
        "1525":{
            "OfferFile":{
                "offer_id":"717"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If so, you would get the integers with the following code:

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
$ids = array_keys($json['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` to parse your :

```
$json = json_decode('{..your data..}', true);
$data = $json['data']['data'];
```

The `$data` variable is an array. To get "1131" and "1525", you need to get array_keys of `$data` via :

```
$vals = array_keys($data);
$1131 = $vals[0];
$1525 = $vals[1];
```